# Phonegap facebook plugin get users email and birthday?

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm using [this](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) plugin in my project:

I need to get the users birthday and email once they allow the app to access their information.

And I'm using this code:

```
function loginWithFB(){
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile","email"],function(result){
    //calling api after login success
     facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me?fields=email,name,picture",
     ["public_profile","email"]
     ,function(userData){
         //API success callback
         alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
      },function(error){
         //API error callback
         alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
   },function(error){
      //authenication error callback
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
     });
}
```

This will only return the users image URL and their full name. So no email at all!

So i tried to do this:

```
function loginWithFB(){
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email","user_birthday"],function(result){
    //calling api after login success
     facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me?fields=email,name,picture,user_birthday",
     ["email","user_birthday"]
     ,function(userData){
         //API success callback
         alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
      },function(error){
         //API error callback
         alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
   },function(error){
      //authenication error callback
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
     });
}
```

But this will give me an error in the alert(); which says 'there was an error making the graph call"! which is not a really helpful error reporting.

Can someone please let me know how I can get the users email and birthday from the graph?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I even tried this and this only returns the user ID instead of email.

```
function loginWithFB(){
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"],function(result){
    //calling api after login success
     facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me?fields=email",
     ["email"]
     ,function(userData){
         //API success callback
         alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
      },function(error){
         //API error callback
         alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
   },function(error){
      //authenication error callback
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
     });
}
```

Comment: Stop confusing permission names with field names. `user_birthday` is the name of the permission, not the field - so of course that gets you an error. And the user’s email is only returned if it is verified. There are also some edge cases where you won’t get it returned even then, due to obscure privacy settings. So don’t _rely_ on getting one (that would not make sense to begin with, cause lots of users who signed up using the mobile might not even have an email on file with Facebook.)

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks. that answers everything.